# Convert point(x,y) within bounding box[(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4)] to account for heading

Tags: point, bounding-box, coordinate-systems

Need help converting a point (716, 493) within a bounding box to the perspective of a 0 degree heading.

- Current heading: 307
- point: 716, 493
- x1: 711, y1: 554
- x2: 659 ,y2: 519
- x3: 708, y3: 479
- x4: 758, y4: 512

Currently this point is accurate with a heading of 307 degrees but I need to move this point to be from a 0 degree heading perspective.  Reason for conversion is I am overlaying this point on top of another bounding box with perspective of 0 degree heading.  As you can imagine the point is off by whatever degree difference is between heading of current point and 0 degrees, but I'm not sure how to calculate what the point x,y should be.

Any help is appreciated!!

For all the non-geniuses like me I found a algorithm to rotate a point about an origin by a certain number of degrees:

```
function rotate(origin, point, angle){
var ox = origin[0];
var oy = origin[1];

var px = point[0];
var py = point[1];

var qx = ox + Math.cos(angle) * (px - ox) - Math.sin(angle) * (py - oy);
var qy = oy + Math.sin(angle) * (px - ox) + Math.cos(angle) * (py - oy);

return [qx,qy];
}

rotate([0,0],[716,493],-53 * Math.PI/ 180)
```

So I believe this is correct.  angle needs to be in radians.  So I wanted to rotate my point from 307 to 90 degrees so I took the difference of 360 - 307 = 53 then I negate the angle to move that many degrees clockwise.

Hope this helps someone who is a non-geniuses like me.  And if this is wrong, well sorry my post was given a -1 so no one else would look at it and give ideas.

Comment: I see that this question was given a -1 could I get details why?

Comment: I didnt quite know where to start on how to do this.  That is why I posted here.  I think its really sad that someone would just mark me down without and explanation or even a pointer.  Like saying hey this is basic geometry.

Comment: I think the reason you got downvoted is because it is unclear what you mean by the heading of a point inside a bounding box. A picture would probably help.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  Next time I post I will try to be more clear.

Comment: We also don't know what language you are asking about and so on...